# Extract key value string into array with regular expressions

Tags: php, regex

I have an array of elements that looks like:

```
$lang = array(
    [0] => lang.language = "Language";
    [1] => lang.update = "Update";
    [2] => lang.lblbasket = "Basket";
);
```

and I am trying to convert it to:

```
$lang = array(
    [language] => Language,
    [update] => Update,
    [lblbasket] => Basket
);
```

I have managed to do that un-elegantly, but I would like a better way of doing it and I know I can achieve it via the regexp, but not quite sure how to do it

This is how I managed to do it

```
for($i=0; $i<count($dumpArray); $i++) {
    if (substr($dumpArray[$i], 0, 5 ) == 'lang.') {
        list($lang_label, $lang_value) = explode('=', $dumpArray[$i]);
        $language[substr(trim($lang_label), 5)] = trim(str_replace('"', '', $lang_value));
    }
}
```

although I should add an extra function to remove the semi-column from the end of the string.
I hope someone can help.

Thanks,
Alesandro

Comment: Is this perl? Please add language tag.

Comment: is it a multidimensional array and are you sure, this is php, i am taking about the syntax of your array

Comment: downvote ?? its a proof this page was visited by one loose canon,  I guarentee who ever downvoted two answer and the question is one person not multiple person, case closed!

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr = [
    'lang.language = "Language";',
    'lang.update = "Update";',
    'lang.lblbasket = "Basket";',
];

foreach ($arr as $v) {
    preg_match('/^.*?\.(.*?) = "(.*?)";$/', $v, $matches);
    $arr2[$matches[1]] = $matches[2];
}
print_r($arr2);
```

Regex explanation is here: https://regex101.com/r/sp9dpC/2

Comment: Also worth mentioning that PHP has very easy to use i18n built in: http://php.net/gettext

Comment: Thanks Miken32, your solution worked like a charm.
The only issue I might foresee is if the equal sign (inside the string) might not have any space before or after it (in the original language file).
Other then that, it works great.
Thanks again

Comment: @jack to make the spaces optional, merely add a `?` after the space.  `/^[^=.]*\.([^= ]*) ?= ?"(.*)";$/`

Answer (score 0):

A regex solution would be fairly simple if you use capture groups:

```
$lang = [];
$regex = '/^lang\.(\S+)\s*=\s*"([^"]*)";$/';
foreach ($dumparray as $str) {
    if (preg_match($regex, $str, $match) === 1) {
        $lang[match[1]] = match[2];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change your line from:

```
$language[substr(trim($lang_label), 5)] = trim(str_replace('"', '', $lang_value));
```

to this:

```
$lang_value = trim(str_replace('"', '', $lang_value);    
$language[trim($lang_label)] = substr($lang_value, 0, strlen($lang_value)-1);
```

or

```
$language[substr(trim($lang_label), 5)] = trim(str_replace(array('"', ';'), '', $lang_value));
```

Comment: I am trying to use regular expressions to for a more elegant and faster solution. Having to use one regex rather then several core functions to resolve the problem seems more viable, practical and faster solution

Answer (score -2):

Just use explode and built a new array

```
$lang = array(
    'lang.language' => "Language",
     'lang.update' => "Update",
     'lang.lblbasket' => "Basket",
);

foreach ($lang as $key =>$language)
{
    $split_lang = explode('.',$key);
        $final[$split_lang[1]] = $language ;
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($final);
```

**result**

```
Array
(
    [language] => Language

    [update] => Update

    [lblbasket] => Basket
)
```